# SQL Server: Order cols in a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-columns

I want to swap the value of columns to have them sorted.

Table:

```
pid | category1 | category2 | category3
----+-----------+-----------+----------
 1  |    a      |    b      |
 2  |    b      |    a      |
 3  |    a      |    c      |    b
```

Result should be:

```
pid | category1 | category2 | category3
----+-----------+-----------+----------
 1  |    a      |    b      |
 2  |    a      |    b      |
 3  |    a      |    b      |    c
```

My approach was to select the columns to rows, order them in groups an return the new columns:

```
pid | category
----+---------
 1  |   a
 1  |   b
 2  |   b
 2  |   a
 3  |   a
 3  |   c
 3  |   b
```

I found the pivot function, but didn't really understand how to use it in this context.

Comment: what would you do with a row like `4 | b | c | `?

Comment: The best option of all would be to normalize this data permanently. Then it becomes trivial. When you have columns like category1, category2 you are violating 1NF by having repeating groups.

Comment: I think you want unpivot not pivot, which would normalize it better as suggest by @SeanLange

Answer (score 1):

Sean Lange is right about how you should correct your database schema.

Here is something to get you your results until then:

Using `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot your data along with `row_number()` to reorder your `category` inside a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx); then repivoting that data with conditional aggregation:

```
;with cte as (
select 
    t.pid
  , u.category
  , rn = row_number() over (partition by t.pid order by u.category)
from t
  cross apply (values (category1),(category2),(category3)) u(category)
where nullif(u.category,'') is not null  
)
select 
    pid
  , category1 = max(case when rn = 1 then category end) 
  , category2 = max(case when rn = 2 then category end) 
  , category3 = max(case when rn = 3 then category end)
from cte
group by pid
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/GIG22558

returns:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| pid | category1 | category2 | category3 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1 | a         | b         | NULL      |
|   2 | a         | b         | NULL      |
|   3 | a         | b         | c         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pivot as below

```
select * from (
    select *, RowN = row_number() over(partition by pid order by Category) from Categories
    ) a
    pivot (max(category) for RowN in ([1],[2],[3])) p
```

Output as below:

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Pid | Category1 | Category2 | Category3 |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1 | a         | b         | NULL      |
|   2 | a         | b         | NULL      |
|   3 | a         | b         | c         |
+-----+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

For dynamic list of columns you can use as below:

```
declare @cols1 varchar(max)
declare @cols2 varchar(max)
declare @query nvarchar(max)

--Row Numbers with tally
;with c1 as (
select * from ( values  (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) v(n) )
,c2 as (select n1.* from c1 n1, c1 n2, c1 n3, c1 n4) 
,RowNumbers as ( 
select top (select max(cnt) from (select cnt = count(*) from Categories group by pid ) a) convert(varchar(6), row_number() over (order by (select null))) as RowN 
from c2 n1, c2 n2
)
select  @cols1 = stuff((select ','+QuoteName(RowN) from RowNumbers group by RowN for xml path('')),1,1,''),
        @cols2 = stuff((select ',' + QuoteName(RowN) + ' as '+ QuoteName(concat('Category' , RowN)) from RowNumbers group by RowN for xml path('')),1,1,'')

select @cols1, @cols2

Set @query = ' Select Pid, '+ @cols2 +' from ( '
Set @query += '     select *, RowN = row_number() over(partition by pid order by Category) from Categories) a '
Set @query += ' pivot (max(category) for RowN in (' + @cols1 + ')) p'

--select @query
exec sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Welcome... happy coding